# Modify a default value in the Stringer interface in go

Tags: dataframe, go, interface, gota

I'm looking at the print interface in the gota dataframe here:
https://github.com/kniren/gota/blob/master/dataframe/dataframe.go#L99

I see the default value is shortCols = true, given [here](https://github.com/kniren/gota/blob/master/dataframe/dataframe.go#L101).

When I call the print data frame, how can I override this value to print with shortCols = false when I println?

```
fmt.Println(fil)
```

eg, I'd like to print all columns, rather than just the first 5 as the above produces the below:

```
[31x16] DataFrame

    valA   valB    valC    valD    valE        ...
 0:  578   8.30     491    7959    1.040000    ...
 1:  577   8.30     291    7975    2.050000    ...
 2:  466   16.7     179    6470    3.210000    ...
 3:  592   9.03     194    8212    4.040000    ...
```

Comment: It looks like you cannot short of modifying the library directly. Worse, the function called by `String` is not exported, so you cannot call it yourself. A cursory search for another way to print a `DataFrame` value did no reveal anything. Maybe file a bug on github?

Comment: Nice, any chance you can either write this as an answer I can accept ("It's not possible") or better, show me what lines would need to be modified in the source I linked and we can improve the lib as the answer? :)

Comment: Sure. It'll but up in a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying the library there is nothing you can do.

If modifying the library is an option you have a few possibilities:

1. Change the name of the internal formatting function so it is exported and call that. This is a bit more work, since you need to explicitly call a function every time you want to print a `DataFrame`, but it is a reasonable option if you want to make minimal changes to the way the library works.

   Basically change `print` to `Print` on lines 101 and 104 (I think those are the only occurrences of that function; if not the compiler will be happy to point out the others :P)
2. Change the arguments to `df.print` in the definition of `df.String`. This is positively trivial, but it has the effect of changing the default behaviour, which may or may not be a good thing.

   For this option just change line 101 to return `df.print(true, false, true, true, 10, 70, "DataFrame")` or whatever combination fits your needs.
3. Add a new method for each printing format you want, and explicitly call these new methods. This is more work than #1 or #2, but some people may prefer it.

Personally, I would go with #1, but your question makes #2 sound more like what you want.